# What are the performance improving techniques in HBASE?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

It can be while creating a table or while using other queries like Inserting, updating, deleting on a table.
I understood that using options like BloomFilter, BlockCache can have an impact. But I would like to know the other techniques that will improve the overall throughput. Also can anyone show how to add a BloomFilter on a Hbase table. I'd like to try it for practicing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You question is too general. In order to know how to properly build you DataStore in HBase you should understand its internal logic of the storage and how data is distributed across the regions. This is probably the main place for start. I would recommend you to get acquainted with LSM-tree and how HBase implements it in [this](https://oyermolenko.blog/2017/02/21/hbase-as-primary-nosql-hadoop-storage/) article. After this I would advice you to read about the proper design of the data schema [here](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/rowkey.design.html) as it would play the main role in your performance. Correct schema with good key would make your data properly distributed across the nodes and would avoid you from having such thing as [hotspotting](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase-0.98.6-cdh5.3.8/book/rowkey.design.html). Then you can start looking through optimization techniques like blume filters, BlockCache,  custom secondary indexes and other stuff.

Comment: Okay Alex. I will go thru the material you suggested. Appreciate your inputs.